# I want to provide a perl DBI like interface, using OO

Tags: perl

I want to write a DBI wrapper, provide select/insert/update/delete, and users can choose which database to use. I'm very new to perl OO, I dont know what I'm doing right or not? Could you please review it, and tell me? And any advice is appreciated.

My wrapper directory look like:

```
MyDBI.pm
MyDBI/SQLite.pm
MyDBI/MySQL.pm
```

MyDBI.pm:

```
package MyDBI;
sub new {
    shift; # discard parent class
    my $database=shift || 'MySQL';
    eval {
      require "MyDBI/$database.pm";
    } or die "$database not found\n";

    my $self="MyDBI::$database"->new;
    bless($self,"MyDBI::$database");
    return $self;
}
sub insert { print "parent insert"; } # children will override it
```

MyDBI/MySQL.pm:

```
package MyDBI::MySQL;
require MyDBI;
@ISA=qw(MyDBI);
use DBI;use DBD::mysql;
sub new { #...} # not special
sub insert { print "mysql insert"; }
```

user script:

```
use MyDBI;
my $dbi=MyDBI->new('SQLite');
$dbi->insert;
```

Is this will work? MyDBI::new is different from perltoot, I'm not quite understand it right now, just copy and simulate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Considering that Perl-DBI is already an object oriented module, I'm not 100% sure what you want to accomplish. Perl-DBI does everything you said you want to do. Can you clarify exactly what you are after? By the way, if you want to learn OO-Perl, take a look at the various [Perl Tutorials](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html) that are available on line, or directly from the command line via the `perldoc` command.

Comment: Thanks. Just forget the DBI part. The minimal thing I want to know is the new sub in MyDBI.pm works? Or has any unknown problems?

Comment: If you're starting on OO perl today, you should probably start with [Moose](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose). And maybe check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for an ORM where the db tables and records map to objects and which offer data manipulation methods like insert, update and select, then see [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass) or [Rose::DB::Object](https://metacpan.org/module/Rose%3a%3aDB%3a%3aObject). Each has its pros and cons, but Rose::DB::Object might be slightly easier to get started on.